# How to create repeated plt.show() instances?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I wish to create different plots corresponding to changing inputs from users (which comes as a list from a while loop). The plt.show() function creates only one instance of the plot. Consider the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 50))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', aspect='equal')
ax = initialize_plot(ax)
messages = []
while(1):
        command = input()
        if command == 'end':
                break
        else:
                if 'add' in command:
                        adder = str(command[command.find('(')+1:command.find(')')])
                        message = list(map(int,adder.split(sep = ',')))
                        messages.append(message)
                elif 'del' in command:
                        deleter = int(command[command.find('(')+1:command.find(')')])
                        del messages[int(deleter+1)]
                plot_lines(lines)
                process_table = [send(message) for message in messages]
                print(*process_table, sep='\n')
                plt.show()
```

The function `send(message)` runs the plotting routine. 
Now, when I give the second list through console, the plotting routine runs but plot does not show. I tried calling the plotting routine from a different file by separating the file for inputs and plotting.

```
from unicast_user1 import perform
messages = []
print("ENTER COMMAND")
while(1):
        command = input()
        if command == 'end':
                break
        else:
                if 'add' in command:
                        adder = str(command[command.find('(')+1:command.find(')')])
                        message = list(map(int, adder.split(sep=',')))
                        messages.append(message)
                        print(*messages, sep = '\n')
                elif 'del' in command:
                        deleter = int(
                            command[command.find('(')+1:command.find(')')])
                        del messages[int(deleter)]
                perform(messages)
```

The problem persists. The full code of file is here user1 - [1](https://github.com/lakshyapriyadarshi/distributed_system_visualization/blob/master/unicast_user1.py) caller - [2](https://github.com/lakshyapriyadarshi/distributed_system_visualization/blob/master/unicast_caller.py)

I wish to create a user-interactive version of the plot (the list can be dynamically modified) that is created by this [file](https://github.com/lakshyapriyadarshi/distributed_system_visualization/blob/master/unicast_generalize.py) (the list is static and complete). The plot is: [this](https://github.com/lakshyapriyadarshi/distributed_system_visualization/blob/master/plot.png)

Comment: Could you provide an example input and the expected output?

Comment: You could either use interactive mode (`plt.ion()`) or run the loop within the event loop of the plotting window.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The `plt.ion()` solution works fine, even on invoking it just once for multiple runs. Thank you.